# Angularjs $resource and json file as mock

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I've got a factory like that :

```
app.factory('AccordDepartement', function($resource, HttpCache) {    
            return  $resource('mocks/departements.json', {}, {
                query: {
                    isArray: true,
                    method:'GET',
                    cache: HttpCache
                },
                metropole: {
                    isArray: true,
                    method:'GET',
                    params: {metropole:true},
                    cache: HttpCache
                }
            });
        });
```

And i use it in a service like that :

```
 AccordDepartement.metropole(function (data) {
     console.log(data);
 });
```

But the matter is that it seems parameters are ignored.

Is it because my url is a json file ? Or i miss something important here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$resource` will return the response for the server. 
In this case, using a static json file, will be the same json for every request that you made because there is no server logic to create the json data dinamically.

Consider to use a different json file for your second request, to mock an specific json what you want.